# iOS Notification or Control center displayer event

Tags: ios, controls, center

In my app I need to know when Notification or Control center are displayed (I'm displaying some information when app goes to background). In my AppDelegate I "listen" to events like when app goes to background, etc... I workd for all cases....except for Notification or Control center. It is very weird that AppDelegate receives "applicationDidBecomeActive" event when Notification center is displayed. Control center works like it should btw. That makes no sense to me.

Anybody have solution/info regarding this?

Comment: What isn't working? When the notification centre is displayed your app doesn't go to the background, but it is no longer the active app, so the App delegate calls are correct.

Comment: Um, last event when Notification center is being displayed is "applicationDidBecomeActive". This is problem. Control center does not have this problem.